# Update a column in database based on the input values for the adjacent column in C# (razor pages)

Tags: c#, .net-core, scheduling, razor-pages

I have a form that takes the preference of students as input, namely UserID, name of the course, the category to which it belongs and their priority to that course. These values are then stored in a table in the database. 
There is an additional column in the database called Priority points whose value depends on whether or not the student has taken a course in the mentioned category earlier.

For example: If the student has already taken a course in Quality, then the priority point should be set to 10 and if he has not taken a course in Quality, the priority point is set to 40.

This should be automatically set by comparing the input category with the history of the user.

The history is a separate table in the database.

I am working with Asp.net razor pages (C#)

This is what I have done so far:
C#:

```
public class AddPreferenceModel : PageModel
    {

        public CUser User { get; set; }
        public CStudent Student { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public CPreference Preference { get; set; }
        public COffers Offers { get; set; }

        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
        private readonly CDataContext _context;
        private readonly IEmailService _emailServices;
        private readonly IUserService _UserService;

        public AddPreferenceModel(IUserService UserService, CDataContext context, IHostingEnvironment IHostingEnvironment, IUserService IUserService, IEmailService emailService)
        {
            _environment = IHostingEnvironment;
            _UserService = UserService;
            _context = context;
            _emailServices = emailService;

            User = _UserService.GetUser();
        }

        public CHistory History { get; set; }
        public IList<CPreference> Pref { get; set; }
        public IList<CHistory> Hist { get; set; }
        public IList<COffers> Off { get; set; }
        public IList<CStudent> stud { get; set; }

        public ActionResult OnGet()            
        {
            if (User.Role != Role.Admin && User.Role != Role.Student)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("/Denied");
            }
            return Page();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            foreach (var item in stud)
            {
                foreach(var item_hist in Hist)
                {
                    if(Preference.Category == History.History)
                    {
                        General.AddPreference = false;
                        return RedirectToPage("/Denied");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        General.AddPreference = true;
                        _context.Preference.Add(Preference);
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
return RedirectToPage("IndexPref");*/

        }
    }
```

And on HTML side:

```
<div class="Custom-Content Custom-Max-Width-800">
    <h2 class="h2">Add your preference</h2>

    <p>
        Please check all the details before submitting
    </p>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="orderForm" method="post">
        <div class="col-md-12"><hr /></div>
        <h4 class="h4 Custom-H4-Less-Margin-Bottom">Preference</h4>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-6">
            User
            <input asp-for="Preference.StudentUser" type="text" value="" required="" />
        </div>

        <div class='col-md-12'><hr /></div>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
            Course Name
            <input asp-for="Preference.name" type="text" value="" required="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
            Category
            <select asp-for="Preference.Category" required>
                <option value="Economics">Economics</option>
                <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                <option value="Quality">Quality</option>
                <option value="Extracurricular">Extracurricular</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
            Priority
            <select asp-for="Preference.Priority" required>
                <option value="High">High</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="Low">Low</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        @if(General.AddPreference == false)
        {
            <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
                <input asp-for="Preference.Priopoints" type="text" value="10" /> 
            </div> 
        }
        @if(General.AddPreference == true)
        {
            <div class="Custom-Form col-sm-4">
                <input asp-for="Preference.Priopoints" type="text" value="40" />
            </div>
        }
                <br />

        <div class="Custom-Form col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Add" class="Custom-Button" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I added a class called General with static variables in it to act as Global variable. 
This is what it looks like:

```
public class General
{
    public static COffers GOffers = new COffers();
    public static COffers Offers
    {
        get { return GOffers; }
        set { GOffers = value; }
    }

    public static bool GAddPreference = true;
    public static bool AddPreference
    {
        get { return GAddPreference; }
        set { GAddPreference = value; }
    }
}
```

I am obviously getting an error message. But I am not sure how else to implement the idea. Any inputs on how to improvise/change would be appreciated. Thanks.

The error is at

```
 foreach (var item in stud)
```

The error is System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: What error are you getting? Your question is pretty broad as written. Ideally a more specific and narrow question needs to be asked.

Comment: The question is: how to set a value to a column in database by comparing the values in two different columns?

Comment: The variable 'stud' isn't being initialized anywhere. I'm guessing in your OnGet method you should read the list of students from the dbcontext and store it in that variable. Also in the OnPost you also need to either re-initialize that variable or having be set from the page by marking the property with [BindProperty]

Comment: I understand the first part of your answer but the second part is not very clear to me. Could you maybe show me how it could be done? Thanks. :)